# Quality measure for clusters of a metric space embedding of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, clustering, metrics, embeddings, metric-spaces

When evaluating clustering algorithms for networks, we have well-established metrics like [Modularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_%28networks%29) and [Surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surprise_%28networks%29) for evaluating the quality of the resulting partition.

If we then embed our graph (well) in a metric space, it becomes much easier to compute distances and communities using geometric algorithms on the points, at the cost of losing our link structure.  Therefore, given a partitioning of the points in the metric space (into, say, k clusters) are there any well-established metrics for computing the quality of the clusters?

And if such metrics exist, can we say anything about what embedding/clustering methods are likely to yield clusters that yield similar results when moving from a graph to its embedding?